# Django ModelViewSet increase foreign key list limit

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using the `django-rest-framework` to make entries into the database, and can make POST requests from there, and select foreign keys from a drop down list for each attribute. However, the limit of entries to select is set to 1000, so when it surpasses this then I cannot select what I want.

In the below image you would see this limit in the Owner drop down list.

[image: html form]

In my example below I have more than 1000 Owner entries in the database. How can I increase this limit?

```
class CatViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Cats.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CatSerializer
    filter_fields = '__all__'
    
    
class CatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cats
        fields = '__all__'
        
        
class Cat(models.Model):
    pwner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField()


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'cats', CatViewSet)

urlspatterns = [
    path(r'', include(router.urls))
]
```

Comment: Are you talking about pagination limit?

Comment: @Charnel I don't think so. Please see updated question with attached screenshot.

Comment: I think this is the [reason](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#limiting-the-number-of-editable-objects) of your issue - by default the number of editable objects limited to 1000. Yet, it's not that obvious of how to override this for auto-created DRF forms.

Comment: I would suggest you use `Raw data` instead and just send json.